# clothsimulation using opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

some portion of my code where I m getting error,in line 249,252 and 255

```
void drawTriangle(Particle *p1, Particle *p2, Particle *p3, const Vec3 color)
{
    glColor3fv( (GLfloat*) &color );
    glNormal3fv((GLfloat *) &(p1->getNormal().normalized() ));  //line 249
    glVertex3fv((GLfloat *) &(p1->getPos() ));

    glNormal3fv((GLfloat *) &(p2->getNormal().normalized() ));   //line 252
    glVertex3fv((GLfloat *) &(p2->getPos() ));

    glNormal3fv((GLfloat *) &(p3->getNormal().normalized() ));  //line 255
    glVertex3fv((GLfloat *) &(p3->getPos() ));
```

I am getting the following error

```
 abc.cpp:249:58: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
 abc.cpp:252:58: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
 abc.cpp:255:58: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the return type of

```
p1->getNormal().normalized()
```

is a value, it is a temporary value that doesn't have an address.

However if you store it in a varilable

```
auto instance = p1->getNormal().normalized();
```

You can take the address of `instance`.  If this is a good idea or not depends on if `glNormal3fv` expects that pointer to be valid longer than the scope of your function.

Comment: Fortunately that is not the case. The GL `...v` functions are just used to pass arrays, and the address does not need to be valid after they return. The only functions that actually use the address long after the call returns actually have the word `...Pointer` in their name.