# Cloth simulation with OpenGL and C++

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to run this C++ code in this link:
https://searchcode.com/codesearch/raw/108480099/
and I am getting errors with this part:

```
void drawTriangle(Particle *p1, Particle *p2, Particle *p3, const Vec3 color)
{
glColor3fv( (GLfloat*) &color );
glNormal3fv((GLfloat *) &(p1->getNormal().normalized() ));  //line 249
glVertex3fv((GLfloat *) &(p1->getPos() ));

glNormal3fv((GLfloat *) &(p2->getNormal().normalized() ));   //line 252
glVertex3fv((GLfloat *) &(p2->getPos() ));

glNormal3fv((GLfloat *) &(p3->getNormal().normalized() ));  //line 255
glVertex3fv((GLfloat *) &(p3->getPos() ));
}
```

The error:

```
249:58: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
        glNormal3fv((GLfloat *) &(p1->getNormal().normalized() ));
252:58: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
        glNormal3fv((GLfloat *) &(p2->getNormal().normalized() ));
255:58: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive] 
        glNormal3fv((GLfloat *) &(p3->getNormal().normalized() ));
```

This question actually was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251113/clothsimulation-using-opengl):

> If you store it in a variable
>   `auto instance = p1->getNormal().normalized();`
>   You can take the address of `instance`.

I'm sorry I don't understand the answer. How to apply it?

I am brand new to C++ and just wish to be able to run the simulation.
I apologize if I question in a wrong way.

Comment: I did mention that the question was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Error says it all:

> error: taking address of temporary

You should NOT take address of a temporary object returned by a function.

```
  GLfloat localObj = p1->getNormal().normalized();
  glNormal3fv((GLfloat *) &(localObj));  //line 249
```

Solution is to define a new object in your function and assign/copy temporary object to it. The new object is local object and will remain valid in the scope of the function.
This will work OK because function `glNormal3fv` does not expected that array being passed should exist forever.

Comment: vcp, you explained very clearly and nicely. Thank you very much. However, I still can't make it work this way. I still get `error: ‘GLFloat’ does not name a type` and `error: ‘localObj’ was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: @Cam: It's `GLfloat` (lowercase 'f'), although if your compiler support C++11 then you can just use `auto` instead.

Comment: Wow! Thank you datenwolf!!! Thanks to vcp again.